# mixed declarations and codes

Tags: c, declaration, compiler-warnings, c89

When I compile function with "gcc -o dene -Wall -ansi -pedantic-errors dene.c"
,gcc emits no error.(can you look a line which starts with char ....,in if loop,)

```
        static void remove_negation(char *s,char *s1) 
          {
             char **cmainp=malloc(sizeof(char*)*1);   
                        int len=0;int d=0; int i=0;
            cmainp[0]=malloc(sizeof(char)*300);
            len=strlen(s);
           for(i=0;i<len;++i)
             { if(s[i]=='-')
               if(i==0 || s[i-1]==',')
      /*look*/  {char *p=malloc(sizeof(char)*3); /*look*/

                ++i;    p[0]=s[i];   p[1]='\0'; 

              strcat(s1,","); strcat(s1,p); free(p);
               continue;
             }
            cmainp[0][d]=s[i]; 
               ++d;
               } cmainp[0][d+1]='\0'; 


             strcpy(cmainp[0],s);
             free(cmainp[0]);
              }
```

But,when compile above function being reformatted with gcc
 ,gcc emits that error;

"dene.c:10: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code"

```
        static void remove_negation(char *s,char *s1) 
          {
             char **cmainp=malloc(sizeof(char*)*1);    
          /*look*/ cmainp[0]=malloc(sizeof(char)*300); /*look*/
                        int len=0;int d=0; int i=0;

            len=strlen(s);
           for(i=0;i<len;++i)
             { if(s[i]=='-')
               if(i==0 || s[i-1]==',')
        {char *p=malloc(sizeof(char)*3);

                ++i;    p[0]=s[i];   p[1]='\0'; 

              strcat(s1,","); strcat(s1,p); free(p);
               continue;
             }
            cmainp[0][d]=s[i]; 
               ++d;
               } cmainp[0][d+1]='\0'; 


             strcpy(cmainp[0],s);
             free(cmainp[0]);
              }
```

And last one,gcc emits following errors

dene.c:16: error: expected expression before ‘char’

dene.c:20: error: ‘p1’ undeclared (first use in this function)

dene.c:20: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

dene.c:20: error: for each function it appears in.)

```
        static void remove_negation(char *s,char *s1) 
          {
             char **cmainp=malloc(sizeof(char*)*1);    

                        int len=0;int d=0; int i=0;
             cmainp[0]=malloc(sizeof(char)*300); 
            len=strlen(s);
           for(i=0;i<len;++i)
             { if(s[i]=='-')
        /*look*/   char *p=malloc(sizeof(char)*3);   /*look*/
               if(i==0 || s[i-1]==',')
              {

                ++i;    p[0]=s[i];   p[1]='\0'; 

              strcat(s1,","); strcat(s1,p); free(p);
               continue;
             }
            cmainp[0][d]=s[i]; 
               ++d;
               } cmainp[0][d+1]='\0'; 


             strcpy(cmainp[0],s);
             free(cmainp[0]);
              }
```

question is why there are differences between them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In K&R and ANSI c, you must always put declarations at the start of a scope block. This requirement is relaxed in c99.

So, whats a scope block? A region delimited by `{` and `}`.

So in you above example the declaration

```
{
   char *p=malloc(sizeof(char)*3); /* ...
```

is OK because it occurs immediately after a `{`, while

```
{
  char **cmainp=malloc(sizeof(char*)*1);    

  /*look*/ cmainp[0]=malloc(sizeof(char)*300); /*look*/

  int len=0;...
```

fails because the assigment comes between the `{` and the second declaration (`int len=0;`).

Comment: can I say that;  { if(s[i]=='-')
               if(i==0 || s[i-1]==',')
              {char *p=malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
,in second example, char *p .. will be created only if two if statement are satisfied

Comment: You can, be aware however, that variable created in a scope go *out of scope* when you reach the matching `}`, and accessing them after that is an error.

Comment: Were pre C89 compilers even stricter? I mean was the requirement that declarations start at the beginning of every function block or every block? I mean was `foo() { int i; for(i=0; i<n; i++) { int j; for(j=0; j<n; j++) {}}}` legal pre C89 compilers?

Comment: @Zboson No idea. I learned c after the ANSI standard on compilers that were mostly complaint with it. I've only ever written K&R for grins and used the compatibility mode of some ANSI compiler for it.

Answer (score 1):

The problems is that your flag "-ansi" imposes the rules of ANSI C, among which is that declarations may appear only at the beginning of a block and not anywhere else interleaved with other statements.

Note that in your first example, the opening brace `{` after the if begins a new block, and hence it is legal to declare new variables there. In your second example, you declare "int len" in the same block as "char **cmainp", but after an assignment to "cmainp". If you place the assignment after the declaration, then everything will be fine, since the declaration would then be at the start of a block.

Answer (score 1):

With the "dene.c:10: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code" error you are defining `char *p=malloc(sizeof(char)*3)` in the middle of the code. ANSI C requires that the declaration appear *only* at the beginning of the block of code and nowhere else. If instead you put char `*p` at the beginning of the code and then `*p=malloc(sizeof(char)*3)` on line 10 this "error" would go away.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do the declarations before you do anything.